# How to add browser Launch Profile to .NET MAUI Blazor (Preview) Project?

Tags: visual-studio, maui, maui-blazor

I'm doing research on .NET MAUI Blazor (Preview).

Currently my approach is to create a seperate Blazor WASM project to develop my razor components where I can debug them directly in Chrome, Firefox, ...

Then I have a seperate .NET MAUI Blazor project which I use to test on native iOS & Android devices.

Eventually this approach works, but I'm wondering if it's possible to add a Browser Launch Profile in my .NET MAUI Blazor Project so I don't need to test via 2 seperate projects.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I've been googling a lot but can't seem to find any relevant information. Is this already possible or too early? Thanks in advance!

[image]

TL;DR: How can I get "Google Chrome" added to the list of Launch Profiles?

Comment: We can't add `Google Chrome` as a launch profile , only what can we do is to enable the browser developer tools in project  , see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=windows .

Comment: Thanks for the reply Colex! I understand, that's what I'm currently doing. It works, but the developer experience would be so much better with the possibility to add those launch profiles. Who knows, somewhere in the future?